# How do I swap tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, locking, alter-table

Suppose, I have a table `foo`, which contains some statistics that are computed every now and then. It is heavily used by other queries.

That's why I want to compute more recent statistics in `foo_new` and swap them when computation is ready.

I could do

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME foo_tmp;
ALTER TABLE foo_new RENAME foo;
```

but what happens if a query needs table `foo` inbetween those two lines when there is no table `foo`? I guess I have to lock it somehow... or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use this one command:

```
RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new To foo;
```

It is an atomic operation: both tables are locked together (and for a very short time), so any access occurs either before or after the `RENAME`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rename-table.html

Comment: One problem with this is that, If I have `tableX` that has got parent constraint referencing `foo`. After this RENAME it will be now referencing `foo_old` but if there are no constraints referencing  `foo` then you should be OK...

Comment: @MarcinWasiluk - yet another drawback to `FOREIGN KEYs`.

Comment: Also worth being aware that RENAME TABLE has to wait for existing queries on the table to finish until it can be executed. That would be fine, but it also locks out other queries while waiting for RENAME to happen! This can cause a serious locking up of your database tables (it has for us). This applies to innodb!