# Truncating and inserting in a safe transaction on MySQL

Tags: mysql, transaction, rollback, truncate

I am trying to `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` data into a MySQL InnoDB table.

I wanted to make sure that if any statement in the transaction failed, the data will be untouched.

**I can't have an empty or corrupted table if something fails.**

This is how I planned to do it.

1. `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
2. `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name`
3. `INSERT INTO table_name`
4. `COMMIT`

I then learned that `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` [causes an implicit COMMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html), which makes the whole transcation pointless.

I then replaced the `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` with a `DELETE FROM table_name` approach, which wasn't ideal - but that too [causes an implicit COMMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html)!

`DROP TABLE table_name` and `CREATE TABLE table_name` also causes an implicit COMMIT!

What method / logic is best to perform what I am trying to do?

*Using MySQL 5.6.17 64-bit server running on Windows Server 2008 R2*

Comment: When does it say that `DELETE` causes implicit commit ?

Comment: I searched for DELETE on that page. DELETE does not appear at all.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since TRUNCATE TABLE does an implicit commit, ***don't use it***.

As long as the table does not have foreign keys, you can do it quickly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable; 
RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_old,mytable_new TO mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable ... ;
```

If the INSERT succeeds, then run this

```
DROP TABLE mytable_old;
```

If the INSERT rolls back, just revert back

```
RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_zap,mytable_old TO mytable;
DROP TABLE mytable_zap;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This leaves the database in a state where mytable does not exist. Use a RENAME table statement instead, which allows for [two atomic renames](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-do-i-swap-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: @ShlomiNoach Thank you for the quick peer review :-)

Comment: Does it make more sense to insert into the new table before renaming it?

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM t
```

Does *not* cause an implicit commit and should work well. I'm actually using this exact solution in production and see no issue transaction-wise (of course deleting all rows from a large table has a significant impact on the size of the transaction, followed possibly by increased IO, increased size of binary logs etc.)