# How do I swap tables atomically in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, table, replace

How to do I swap two tables in an atomic fashion in Oracle?

I would like to perform the equivalent of:

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME foo_tmp;
ALTER TABLE foo_new RENAME foo;
```

but what happens if a query needs table foo in between those two lines when there is no table foo? Some lock would be required.

P.S. For a MySQL version of the question, see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-do-i-swap-tables-in-mysql).

Answer (score 4):

Create a public synonym that points to the new table.

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM foo FOR foo_new;
RENAME foo TO foo_tmp;

-- At this point in time, any DMLs for foo will operate on foo_new, via the synonym 

RENAME foo_new TO foo;
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM foo;
```

Things will get a bit more complicated if you're accessing the tables involved with a user other than the schema owner, but this works if you're only accessing the table with the schema owner.

Comment: What happens between `RENAME foo_new TO foo; DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM foo;`?  Does the synonym readjust itself atomically with the rename, or is there a gap between the two DDLs where if a query would come in between the two, the synonym would point to a non existing table?

Comment: It depends on the logged in user. For it to work correctly the logged in user has to own the table

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create synonyms on tables that already exist.  You should get this error: ORA-00955.  While a public synonym will only work when you don't specify schemas when addressing objects e.g. select * from foo rather than select * from larry.foo.  Furthermore public synonyms are inherently a security risk.  Instead you can switch to green/blue deployments.

Set up your object for green/blue

```
-- rename your table/mv/view this will make your object unavailable one last time
alter table foo rename to foo_green;
-- create your synonym
create SYNONYM foo for foo_green;
```

```
-- make a new version of foo
create table foo_blue as select * from foo;
-- update your synonym.  This will swap the tables 
create or replace SYNONYM foo for foo_blue;
```

It should be fairly straightforward to script out swapping tables in an out by determining which table the synonym is currently point to.